# Load the PHP contents only after switching a nav tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 10 tabs on my project, each of them will fetch some values from API using PHP.
It takes 10-15 seconds to load the page every time (since it updates the values for all 10 Tabs)

How do i load content **only after switching a tab**?

**Load TAB1 at start**, then **only after clicking TAB2 or TAB3** **then load their content, but do not load them at start**

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/t52mwLoc/

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">

    <h4 class="card-title">Default Tab</h4>
                          
                          
                                                <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active show" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-selected="true">TAB1</a> </li>
      
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab" aria-selected="false"> TAB2</a> </li>
                            
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" role="tab" aria-selected="false"><span class="hidden-sm-up"> TAB3</a> </li>
                            
    </ul>

<!-- Tabs -->
<div class="tab-content tabcontent-border">
<div class="tab-pane active show" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
<div class="p-20">
Load this content... [TAB1]
</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane  p-20" id="tab2" role="tabpanel">some PHP... Load this ONLY after clicking [TAB2]</div>
<div class="tab-pane p-20" id="tab3" role="tabpanel">some PHP... Load this ONLY after clicking [TAB3]</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can achieve this by putting the content for each tab under it's own URL endpoint. Then you can hook to the `show.bs.tab` event when the tab is clicked on, to make an AJAX request to load the content.

Comment: Each Tab should very much be its own page, if you want it to seem like its all one page do as @RoryMcCrossan suggestions

Comment: Something like this? https://pastebin.com/raw/fbTpEu15  Do i add my PHP code inside an array? Could you please show me an example?

Comment: @DevWithZachary That also sounds like a solution to my problem,  but indeed all loading in the same page after clicking on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simple thing you can do is this. live example [here](https://koding-khurram.herokuapp.com/stackoverflow/questions/70167484/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function initialLoad(){
      $('#loader').load("page1.php");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialLoad()">
  Click on buttons to load different pages <br/>

  <button style="margin-left: 20px" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="load(1)"> Page 1 </button>
  <button style="margin-left: 20px" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="load(2)"> Page 2 </button>
  <button style="margin-left: 20px" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="load(3)"> Page 3 </button>
  <button style="margin-left: 20px" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="load(4)"> Page 4 </button>
  <button style="margin-left: 20px" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="load(5)"> Page 5 </button><br/><br/>

  <div class="load" id="loader">
  </div>
  <h3>You can check the network tab to see which page is getting loaded</h3>

  <script>
  function load(page){
    var thePage = "page"+page+".php"
    $('#loader').load(thePage);//assuming u have page1.php page2.php like this
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For any queries comment down.

Comment: One question, How to prevent users from navigating/accessing the full URL path of the .php file?         Examples, don't allow users to access these; [page1.php](https://koding-khurram.herokuapp.com/stackoverflow/questions/70167484/page1.php)  -  [page2.php](https://koding-khurram.herokuapp.com/stackoverflow/questions/70167484/page2.php)

Comment: As I 'am using xhr, I don't think it's possible, every request made is according to the URL, and if you block a direct URL, you will not be able to `load()` it either, you need to find some other way of hiding/protecting pages/data.